# mongodb array of objects insert with specified index

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have an array of objects that i am aiming at inserting in a document with a predefined index.

```
db.getCollection("Service").update(
{
"service.serviceCode": "ddxxsxs"},{
$push: {
    "service.serviceDetails.socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail": {
    $each: [
            {
                "name": "Sample",
                "link": "sample@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                $position:3
            }
        ]
    }
}});
```

i am actually aiming to insert the above as the 4th object in my array. but the above is given me an exception.
I need help on achieving the this pls.

Comment: "an exception"?

Comment: i meant to say it's not inserting with this errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$position' in 'service.serviceDetails.socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail..$position' is not valid for storage."

Comment: Try `{
$push: {
    "service.serviceDetails.socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail": {
    $each: [
            {
                "name": "Sample",
                "link": "sample@gmail.com"
            }],
                $position:3
    }
}}`

Comment: Thanks it worked @veeram